# Displaying angular 2 data in groups

Tags: angular

I have an angular 2 app where I want to display customer reviews in groups of 3 and each group would be part of a slider, so you can slide through all the reviews. I'm unsure how to group these though. I can manage to display the first 3, but I don't know how to get subsequent groups of 3 to work. My code currently looks like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let review1 of businessReviews.list; let index2=index">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="row">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let review of businessReviews.list; let index=index">
                <ng-container *ngIf="(index) < 3">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="review">
                            {{review.text}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

I'm pretty sure I need to add something to the ngIf to compare the outer loop with the inner loop, but I'm unsure what I need to add.

Comment: Not enough info to help you, you need to give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MikeTung All of the information required is supplied in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use angular directives, I would recommend trying to format your array into groups in typescript.

Example of grouping:

```js
var groupedList = [];
[1,2,3,4,5].forEach((num, i, arr)=>{
  if(i % 3 == 0) groupedList.push([]);
  groupedList[groupedList.length-1].push(num);
});

console.log(groupedList);
```

Then in your html....

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of groupedList; let index=index">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="review" *ngFor="let review of groupedList[i];">
        {{review.text}}
      </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Now we iterate the groupedList and then inside we iterate each review.